# How to show this structured info from database using mySQL/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I believe my title says it, I have a mySQL database that contains the following columns:

```
id -- timestamp

1 -- 2014-09-15 10:22:40
1 -- 2014-09-15 10:13:30
1 -- 2014-09-14 10:11:10
2 -- 2014-09-14 10:20:40
2 -- 2014-09-14 10:19:30
3 -- 2014-09-13 10:17:10
```

How can I show the visits made by user_id per day? Meaning:

```
id 1 2014-09-15 visited 2 times
id 1 2014-09-14 visited 1 times
id 2 2014-09-14 visited 2 times
id 3 2014-09-13 visited 2 times
```

Comment: use "group by" on timestamp field

Comment: @Khushboo in my opinion I don't think that this is the answer...

Comment: select id,date_format(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d') `day`, count(id) visits from mytable group by id,date_format(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by getting date value from `timestamp` column and group by id and date value

```
select id,
date(`timestamp`) per_day,
count(*)
from test
group by id,per_day
order by id,per_day desc
```

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/640e67/5)

Comment: Thank you. `select token, date(`time`) per_day, count(*) from generalrow group by token,per_day ORDER BY count(*) DESC`